# Received memory warning in create image file

Tags: ios

I use this code get album pictures, and create file in the documents, but there will be Received memory warning, then crash。

Here is the code that I used. Can anyone tell me what did I do wrong?

```
 NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

   ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock = ^(NSError *myerror){
       NSLog(@"error occour =%@", [myerror localizedDescription]);
   };

   ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock groupEnumerAtion = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){

       if (result!=NULL) {
           //we can get all the things in the defaultRepresentation such as size info in UTI
       }

       //just fetching photos
       if ([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto]) {

          //copy image to the path:Documents/DMS/Photo
           ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [result defaultRepresentation];

           NSString *tt = [rep filename];

           NSString *fullPath = [pathPhoto stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@",tt];

           if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fullPath]){

               UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithCGImage:[rep fullScreenImage]];

          NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
          [image release];

               [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil];
               NSLog(@"Creat image file fullPath================%@",fullPath);

               //imageData = nil;
               [imageData release];

           }else{
               NSLog(@"---------------------the image is Exist");
            }

         }

    };

   ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock
   libraryGroupsEnumeration = ^(ALAssetsGroup* group, BOOL* stop){

       if (group == nil)
       {
           return;
       }

       if (group!=nil) {
           [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:groupEnumerAtion];
       }
       NSLog(@"finish--------------------------------------------");

       return;
   };

   ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
   [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos
                          usingBlock:libraryGroupsEnumeration
                        failureBlock:failureblock];
   [library release];
```

[pool release];

Comment: are you executing the code you posted in a for loop to handle multiple images?

Comment: Yes,i used ALAssetsGroupEnumerationResultsBlock handle multiple images.thank you‘re reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say that you are using the code you posted inside of a loop, I suppose that what happens is that you app is being killed due to too many auto-released objects being allocated inside of the loop.

You could try using an autorelease pool:

```
for (...) {
   @autoreleasepool {
     <your code here>
   }
}
```

so that the autorelease pool is cleaned up at each iteration (instead of growing all along the whole loop execution).

EDIT:

```
if ([[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto])
{
    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [result defaultRepresentation];

    CGImageRef iref = [rep fullScreenImage];

    NSString *tt = [rep filename];

    if (iref) 
    {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
        if(!image)
        {
            NSLog(@"---------------------the imageData is nil");
        }
        else
        {
            NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

            NSString *fullPath = [pathPhoto stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@.png",tt];

            NSLog(@"fullPath================%@",fullPath);

            if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fullPath])
            {
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:imageData attributes:nil];

                NSLog(@"Creat image file fullPath================%@",fullPath);
            }
        }
        CGImageRelease(iref);
    }
}
```

Comment: i create a pool like this :NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];[pool release];but it look like not work.thank you answered

Comment: ok. would you try Xcode static analyzer to check if you have any memory leaks? after removing any leak, if the issue persist, I would also give a try to Instruments' Leaks tool.

Comment: one more thing: I have checked my own use of `initWithCGImage` and I think that `CGImageRelease(iref);` is needed after it (unless you are doing it elsewhere).

Comment: the leak is that place:NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);I don't know whether it is the cause of the picture too much

Comment: that sounds strange, because `UIImagePNGRepresentation` returns an autoreleased object, so it should not leak. Have you tried releasing `iref` as I was suggesting above? also, check my edit in a couple of minutes...

Comment: Now I use after editing the code, but in create image file 80 zhang's time Received memory warning and crash, use the Instruments' Leaks tool shows no leak, I'm silly off。and thank you very much!!!