# imageWithCGImage: GCD memory issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, core-graphics, grand-central-dispatch

When I perform the following only on the main thread `iref` gets autoreleased immediately:

```
-(void)loadImage:(ALAsset*)asset{
    @autoreleasepool {
        ALAssetRepresentation* rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
        CGImageRef iref = [rep fullScreenImage];
        UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref
                                             scale:[rep scale]
                                       orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

        [self.imageView setImage:image];
    }
}
```

But when I perform imageWithCGImage: with GCD on a background thread `iref` does not get released instantly like in the first example. only after about a minute:

```
-(void)loadImage:(ALAsset*)asset{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            ALAssetRepresentation* rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
            CGImageRef iref = [rep fullScreenImage];
            UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref
                                                 scale:[rep scale]
                                           orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                [self.imageView setImage:image];
            });
        }
    });
}
```

How can I make the `CGImageRef` object to be released immediately?

Prior Research:

- The Leak instrument doesnt show any leaks when I record with it.
- The Allocations instruments shows that a `CGImageRef` object was allocated and is still living for about a minute after it should have been released.
- If I try to manually release the `CGImageRef` object using `CGImageRelease` I get a BAD_EXEC exception after a minute when the image tries to get autoreleased.
- retaining the `iref` using `CGImageRetain` and then using `CGImageRelease` to release it doesnt work.
- similar questions on stackoverflow that didn't help: [image loading with gcd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15572028/image-loading-with-gcd-receiving-memory-warning), [received memory warning in create image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975033/received-memory-warning-in-create-image-file), [memory leak when get fullscreenimage from alaseet result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138296/memory-leak-when-get-fullscreenimage-from-alasset-result),

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off, there's not a notion of an "autoreleased" CF object. You can get into situations where such a thing exists when dealing with toll-free bridged classes, but as you can see, there's a `CFRetain` and a `CFRelease` but no `CFAutorelease`. So I think you're misconstruing the ownership of `iref`. Let's trace ownership throughout this code:

```
-(void)loadImage:(ALAsset*)asset{
```

`asset` is passed into this method. Its retain count is presumed to be at least 1.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
```

The block closure takes a retain on `asset`.

```
        @autoreleasepool {
            ALAssetRepresentation* rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
```

This returns you, by naming convention, an object that you don't own. It might be autoreleased, it might be a singleton/global, etc. But you don't own it and shouldn't take ownership of it by retaining it.

```
            CGImageRef iref = [rep fullScreenImage];
```

Since there's not a notion of an "autoreleased" CF object, we'll presume that `rep` is returning you an inner pointer to a `CGImageRef` owned by `rep`. You also don't own this, and shouldn't retain it. Relatedly you don't control when it will go away. A reasonable guess would be that it will live as long as `rep` and a reasonable guess is that `rep` will live as long as `asset` so you should probably assume that `iref` will live at least as long as `asset`.

```
            UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref
                                                 scale:[rep scale]
                                           orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

If the UIImage needs the CGImageRef to stick around, it will take a retain or make a copy to ensure that it stays alive. (Probably the latter.) The UIImage itself is autoreleased, by naming convention.

```
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
```

This inner block closure is going to take a retain on `image` (and `self`). The block will be copied by libdispatch extending the life of those retains until the block is executed and itself released.

```
                [self.imageView setImage:image];
```

The image view is going to take a retain (or copy) on `image` if it needs to, in order to do its job.

```
            });
```

The inner block is done executing. At some point in the future, libdispatch will release it, which will transitively release the retains taken by the block closure on `self` and `image`.

```
        }
```

Your autorelease pool pops here.  Anything that was implicitly retain/autoreleased should be released now.

```
    });
```

The outer block is done executing. At some point in the future, libdispatch will release it, which will transitively release the retain taken by the block closure on `asset`.

```
}
```

Ultimately, this method cannot control the lifetime of the CGImageRef in `iref` because it never has ownership of it. The implication here is that the CGImageRef is transitively owned by `asset`, so it will live at least as long as `asset`. Since `asset` is retained by virtue of being used in the outer block (i.e retained by the outer block's closure) and since libdispatch makes no promises about when finished blocks will be released, you effectively can't guarantee that `iref` will go away any sooner than libdispatch gets around to it.

If you wanted to go to manual retain/release, and be as explicit about it as possible, you could do this:

```
-(void)loadImage:(ALAsset*)asset{
    __block ALAsset* weakAsset = [asset retain]; // asset +1
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
        @autoreleasepool {
            ALAssetRepresentation* rep = [weakAsset defaultRepresentation];
            CGImageRef iref = [rep fullScreenImage];
            UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] imageWithCGImage:iref
                                                 scale:[rep scale]
                                           orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

            __block UIImage* weakImage = [image retain]; // image +1

            [weakAsset release]; // asset -1

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                [self.imageView setImage: weakImage];
                [weakImage release]; // image -1
            });
        }
    });
}
```

`__block` prevents the block closures from retaining `asset` and `image` allowing you to explicitly retain/release them yourself. This will mean that of all the things you create, all will be explicitly disposed. (`rep` and `image` are presumably retain/autoreleased, but your pool should take care of those.) I believe this is the most explicit you can be about this, given that `asset` is passed in to you, and therefore you don't control how long it lives, and it is ultimately the "owner" (as far as this scope is concerned) of the CGImageRef stored in `iref`.

Hope that clarifies things a bit.

Comment: Thank you for effort! I really appreciate it :) Unfortunately, it didn't work for me :( This is how I implemented your solution https://gist.github.com/eventomer/7133972

Comment: From the gist you posted, I would move the `[assetslibrary release];` out of the main queue dispatch and put it right after `__block ALAsset *weakAsset = [asset retain];`  You never actually use it in any of the blocks. (Unless it going away implicitly makes `asset` invalid.)

Comment: your suspicion was true. if the assetlibrary instant get released it makes the asset invalid. any other idea on how to solve this maybe or should I open a radar at apple?

Comment: How about if you put `[assetslibrary release];` right after `[weakAsset release];`?

Answer (score 2):

You should retain the CGImageRef 
..

```
CGImageRef iref = CGImageRetain([rep fullScreenImage]);
//..before [self.imageView..
CGImageRelease(iref)
```

The rest is just a matter of run loop, in one without GCD the image is released istanneously, in the other is managed by GCD, but is wrong anyway, someone has to take the ownership of iref.

Comment: when i add the cast i get the following error message: Incompatible types casting 'CGImageRef' (aka 'struct CGImage *') to 'CGImageRef' with a __bridge_retained cast

Comment: retaining the iref using CGImageRetain and then using CGImageRelease to release it doesn't work too.

Comment: Try now, the bridge wasn't necessary because they are both CF opaque type